# most secure way to "call" a php file

Tags: php, mysql, server-side-includes

I am creating an app for my clients to add to their webpages. however, I am hosting the database that stores the info for this app. All I want to do is do all the queries on my server and somehow pass the $var to their server.
so what I was thinking was to have my PHP page with all the MYSQL credentials store on my server and give them a code that calls that page and outputs the stuff, something like

```
require_once('192.163.163.163/config.php');
```

But I bet this is the least secure way to do this. I don't want to give anyone access to the central database and I am handling all the requests. Do you guys have any suggestions that I can pull the data off my db and pass it to their server in a $var without opening any doors?

Comment: Incredibly **BAD** idea. You should never **EVER** include/require code from a remote server. it exposes any data that url provides to the world at large. If anyone ever figures out that url, they can grab your DB credentials and get directly into your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't afford to give away your DB credentials or other internal details of your system but you need the clients to be able to read data from you, then the only really secure way to do set your system up as an API that the clients can call.

Don't try to combine the two systems into a single app; it will open up holes that cannot be closed.

To create an API is fairly simple in principle. Just create a suite of normal PHP programs that accept a set of pre-defined arguments return the data in a pre-defined format that can be easily processed by the calling program -- eg maybe a JSON structure.

The clients would then simply call your system via an HTTP call. They'd never need to see your code; the wouldn't need to be hosted on the same server, and they wouldn't even need to be writing their system in the same language as yours.

There's a lot more to it than that -- it is, of course, perfectly easy to write an insecure API as well, and you'll want to read up on how to write a good API to avoid that sort of thing -- but that's your starting point. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I'll go down the API route.